# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. at new t (

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My app was working fine but suddenly it stopped being able to read/write anything to firestore. I thought the problem was with the date but I changed the rules to the following and still get the same error

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 12, 31);
          
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 12, 31);` means that your database rejects reads and writes after December 31, 2020.

If you want to continue to access the database, change the date or (better) [write proper security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) that control exactly what users can do with the data.